# Cmake generates incorrect configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cmake

I use CMake, and on one of my machines, the generation seems to be messy. When I open the project properties in Visual Studio 2010, the debug configuration seems to be a release one: `_DEBUG` is not defined, optimizations are enabled, the linked runtime is the release one (`/MT` and not `/MTd`), etc...

The problem is that it prevent correct build of project depending on dlls compiled using CMake... for example if some parts of the dll are only present in a debug build. I am using CMake 2.8.10.2.

Comment: try to remove generated files and run cmake again.

Comment: @ixSci That seems to work, thank you! You can post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove generated files and run cmake again. It happens sometimes when MSVS is running and you regenerate your project with CMake. Some settings are still keep in MSVS but others are regenerated so you have a mess at the end.